# How to have a <div> that is on the right side of a menu expand as the browser window expands?

Tags: html, css, css-float, width

You must know that this question is very specific to my situation and I would really love to hear what you guys have to say!

So, I am trying to have a page on my website where on the left side there is a menu and on the right side there is the content. I gave the div that contains the menu a width of 200px, but my question is, how do I place the div that contains the content on the right of the side-menu? Because keep in mind that I want the div that contains the content to expand or shrink as the browsers window size changes.

First scenario: 
I floated the side-menu to the left and I also floated the div containing the content to the left, but when I give it a width of 100% it goes under the side-menu.

Second scenario: 
I floated the side-menu to the left and I placed the div containing the content to the right of the side menu by giving it a margin-left of 250px.

But in both of these scenarios the div containing the content doesn't fit the browser's window, meaning if i resized the browser that div won't expand, it  goes under the side-menu.

Question 1:
How do i give the div containing the content a non-fixed width so it can expand or shrink when the browser's window is resized. The side-menu will still be there even when the browser window size shrinks or expands.

Question 2: How do I place the div that contains the content next to the side menu? Do I float it? Do I give it a margin-left? Do I absolutely position it?

Please tell me how to place that div and how to make it expand or shrink and fit different browser window size.

Here is a screenshot of it: (click on the link)

[side menu on the left and content on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4nKx.png)

Comment: You may want to use a grid system, like Bootstrap's grid: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

Comment: Hey, could you show some of your code, to see what we can improve?

Comment: @YouDeserveThat, my code is very simple lol. I added two divs one of them has 250px and is floated left, and the other div is also floated left but i don't know what to do with the width...

Comment: @SteveH. is there any other way without the grid system? Do I use min-width or max-width? Do I use media-queries? It's a very simple layout but it's breaking my head lol

Comment: I can't imagine the code without seeing it and I won't build your solution from scratch, sorry... Just upload your code in a snippet, that's pretty easy :)

Comment: @YouDeserveThat But like what is the general practice in this kind of situations? How do other websites do it? Media-queries?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have not started coding yet. That's a bit of an issue, so my answer is going to be a little dry, but here we go:

> Question 1: How do i give the div containing the content a non-fixed width so it can expand or shrink when the browser's window is resized. The side-menu will still be there even when the browser window size shrinks or expands.

[CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) `flex-basis` might do the trick. If you combine it with [relative units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units) such as percentages.

> Question 2: How do I place the div that contains the content next to the side menu? Do I float it? Do I give it a margin-left? Do I absolutely position it?

Again, using [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

> But like what is the general practice in this kind of situations? How do other websites do it? Media-queries?

Usually media queries is a good way to start, yes. Here is a good guide: [using media queries - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

---

*Holy Grail Layout example:*

[image: Holy Grail Layout example]

1. Follow the guide from MDN : [using CSS Flexible Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)
2. Come here if you got an issue and a piece of code to show so we can help

Hope I helped a bit.

Comment: I'm going to check and read about the flexible boxes and let u know if it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am over-simplifying your question, but using percentages as width works when the browser window size is changed.  You can click "Run code snippet" to see it in action.

```css
#menu,#content {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#menu {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #eee;
}

#content {
  width: 79%;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li>Item one</li>
<li>Item two</li>
<li>Item three</li>
<li>Item four</li>
<li>Item five</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
<p>This is the content that shows up to the right of the menu on the left.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: but in this case the menu expands and shrinks as the window size changes, but I don't want that. I want the menu to have a fixed-width (i want it to stay the same width on any window size) but I want the content to be able to expand and shrink when the window size changes. I'm going to have pictures in the content div and those pictures will resize depending on the screen size but the menu should be the same width. So basically what i need to know is how to make the content div fit every browser size without having a scrollbar that appears.